# Highlight row if column value partially matches in another sheet column

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a client with an old Excel 2010 sheet that needs to highlight rows on Sheet1 if the cell in column B partially matches a value in Sheet2, column A

## Explanation

### Sheet1

In column B we have partial invoice numbers (which don't follow local authority invoice number format)

[image]

### Sheet2

In column A we have complete invoice numbers (that follows the local authority invoice number format)

[image]

The issue is that we need to find which partial invoice numbers from Sheet1 (column **Número Desde**) are present in Sheet2 (column **N_COMP**), and also, the comparisson should be done from right to left so, for example B51 on Sheet1 should not match `A0001000038132` or `A0001002773133` but something more like `A0001000000010` where the last 8 characters of the invoice number should be taken into account because in the invoice number format, the real invoice number is the last 8 characters.

For example Sheet1!B51  should match the red part only.

[image]

Here is the sample dataset to test https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YIt1fH6h-mfQ5sG5CT9faJq-2bYNpzK4/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101129782086412359164&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with conditional formatting, using the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,"*" & TEXT($B2,"00000000"))>0
```

Comment: In my case I have to replace , with ; because of the old Excel 2010

Comment: FYI, replacing commas (`,`) with semi-colons (`;`) is not a function of the version of Excel, but the language settings

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$114;MATCH(B2;VALUE(RIGHT(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$114;7));0))}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the formula throws errors because I have old Excel 2010. Thanks anyway

Comment: @razor7 No, the formula gave an error not because of the old Excel, this formula works even in Excel 2003. You just didn’t pay attention to the curly braces around the formula - this is ***an array formula***, it should be entered by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of the usual Enter. I should have pointed this out in the text of the answer, I didn't, sorry.